# Deleted product of hyperbolic planes

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Suppose I have a Riemann surface, $M$ which admits a metric of negative Guassian curvature.

Is it known if the deleted product:

$M\times M\backslash \{ (m,m) : m\in M\}$ admits a (complete) metric of negative sectional curvature or not?

Comment: Just asking: You mean negative _sectional_ curvature, right? And do you care if the metric is complete?

Comment: Yes, negative sectional curvature and yes complete would be nice...I'll add this to make it more clear.